# Reverse proxy with NGINX and PHP in Docket

Tags: php, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

im trying to do a little lab with NGINX and PHP under Docker. the case is i have a little PHP page calle index_simple.php that is on the PHP container. the thing is im triying to redirect what i receive on the proxi under http://host:80/arso2021 and redirected to http://docker_container:80/index_simple for load the file. this actually is not working. The containers are connected on the same network as you can see on the Docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.666666'
services:
 db:
   container_name: db
   image: mysql:5.7
   restart: always
   environment:
   # Nombre de la base de datos
   MYSQL_DATABASE: 'axsodb'
   # Usuario y password del SQL
   MYSQL_USER: 'jdacostar'
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password1'
   # Contraseña de root
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password1'
   ports:
    - '3306:3306'
   expose:
   # abrimos el puerto 3306
    - '3306'
web-php:
  build:
   context: ./php/
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  depends_on:
   - db
  container_name: web-php
  hostname: arso20212
  volumes:
    - ./html:/var/www/html/
  ports:
    - 5000:80
  networks:
    - lab_network
nginx:
  container_name: reverse_proxy
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./html:/var/www/html/
  networks:
    - lab_network
```

networks:
lab_network:
name: lab_net
driver: bridge

and the nginx.conf file.

```
   events{

   }
   http{
     server{
        listen 80;

       location /arso2021 {
            porxy_pass http://172.0.0.3:5000/index_php.php;
     }


   }
}
```

also on the logs of the nginx i see that always is trying to get the "index_file.php" from his internal storage not from the php server.

also if i change the location from /arso2021 to /index_simple works fine also if i use the rewrite 301 i can load the file index_php.php with the wanted path but the php was not executed.

could someone give me a hand please.

thanks in adavance

kind regards